# Two results about the ring homomorphism $\phi : R \rightarrow \prod_{j=1}^{n}(R/I_j)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm studying commutative algebra and trying to prove two results, stated as follows:

Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi : R \rightarrow \displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{n}(R/I_j)$, where $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$ and $I_1,\dots,I_n$ are ideals of $R$.

1. $\phi$ is surjective if, and only if, $I_r$ and $I_s$ are coprimes whenever $r \neq s$.
2. $\phi$ is injective if, and only if, $\displaystyle\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} I_j = \langle{\overline{0}}\rangle$.

I can't use the isomorphism $\dfrac{R}{I_1 \cdots I_n} \simeq \dfrac{R}{I_1} \times \cdots \times \dfrac{R}{I_n}$, since this was not stated until this result showed up on the text I'm reading. This isomorphism could help me, because if $I_r$ and $I_s$ are coprimes whenever $r \neq s$, then $I_1 \cdots I_n = \displaystyle\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}I_j$.

I have tried to prove (1.), the $(\implies)$ part, using the surjectiveness of $\phi$ and trying to find something that shows $I_r$ and $I_s$ are coprimes whenever $r \neq s$, but I didn't saw anything that could make that happen. Then I tried supposing that there exists $1 \leq r \neq s \leq n$ such that $I_r$ and $I_s$ are not coprimes, in vain again.

I'm really struggling with those two. So, could anyone show me what I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason why you can't use the isomorphism $\frac{R}{I_1 ... I_n} \simeq \frac{R}{I_1} \times ... \times \frac{R}{I_n}$ is because this isomorphism is usually obtained by first proving the theorem you're asked to prove. It would be circular reasoning to prove each proposition from the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second one, notice that:
$ker(\phi)=\{r\in R|\phi(r)=(\bar 0,...,\bar0)\}=\{r\in R|r\in I_s\ \forall s\}=\bigcap I_s$.

$\phi$ is injective $\iff$ $ker(\phi)=\{0\}\iff \bigcap I_s=\{0\}$.

For the first one, we want to show surjectivity. I leave it for you to show that since every pair is coprime, then $(I_1I_2...I_r-1)+I_r=R$. So I'll assume that $r=2$.

Now, there are $a\in I_1, b\in I_2$ s.t $a+b=1$. Therefore, $\phi(a)=(\bar 0,\bar 1)$ - because $1-a\in I_2$, then $\bar a=\bar 1$. Similarly, $\phi(b)=(\bar 1,\bar 0)$.

Now choose element from $R/I_1\times R/I_2$, say $(\bar c,\bar d)$. Then, $\phi(ac,bd)=c(\bar 0,\bar 1)+d(\bar 1,\bar 0)=(\bar c,\bar d)$, so $\phi$ is surjective.  The other direction uses the same arguments only the other way around.

Comment: The part you left me to show I did prove. So, I'll need to use induction to show the first one, right?

Comment: @RodnaleSercem You don't even need induction. The point was to show that you can find a preimage to $e_i=(\bar 0,...,\bar 0,\bar 1,\bar 0,...\bar 0)$. I did it for 2 just because otherwise it's a bit more wordy, but the idea is the same.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much!